# MySQL error - #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sum

I have been trying to update values in a MySQL table and I got this error from running the code below. Help.

```
UPDATE overall
SET Total_Score  = (
SELECT (
       ot.Total_Score + op.Total_Score
       ) AS Total_Score
FROM (
   SELECT StudentID, Total_Score
   FROM term2
   GROUP BY StudentID
  ) AS ot
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT StudentID, Total_Score
       FROM overall
       GROUP BY StudentID
     ) AS op ON ( op.StudentID = ot.StudentID )
)
```

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax instead of correlated query in SET.

Comment: What are you trying to do? An explanation of your purpose, as well as sample data and desired results, would help others understanding your question.